# Dealing with an XSLT Namespace Mismatch

Tags: xml, xslt, rss, youtube, xml-namespaces

So, hopefully this will be my final request for help on this project, as you guys have already helped so much already.

Basically, I'm writing some code that takes a YouTube playlist and converts it to an RSS feed.  I've gotten it to work the way I want to, except for one minor detail: I'm not sure why, but I need to remove one of the namespaces from the YouTube XML before it will compile.

The namespace declaration from YouTube looks like this:

```
<feed xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:gml='http://www.opengis.net/gml' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' xmlns:georss='http://www.georss.org/georss' gd:etag='W/&quot;A04NRn47eCp7I2A9WhJTF0g.&quot;'>
```

Normally, I'd use the exact same ones, except for whatever reason if I include the `xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom'` segment, the whole thing returns null.

Up until now, my technique has been to just chop that line out of the YouTube XML, however this strikes me as a tad inelegant.  If someone who knows more about this than I do could point out what's wrong with my current code, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Adam

EDIT: For reference, here's my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:media='http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:yt='http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007' gd:etag='W/&quot;Ak8EQX47eCp7I2A9WhdSEkQ.&quot;'>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select="entry">
<xsl:if test="yt:position &lt; 3">
    <item>

        <title><xsl:value-of select="title" /></title>
        <xsl:variable name="videoid" select="substring-before(substring-after(media:group/media:content/@url, 'v/'), '?')" />   <!--Extracting the YouTube video ID--> 
        <description>
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$videoid}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true" width="500" height="300"></embed>    <!--Embed code for the video-->
            <br />
            <br />
            <xsl:call-template name="ParseLink">    <!--Parses the video description such that URLs become links-->
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="media:group/media:description" />   
            </xsl:call-template>
            <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$videoid}/hqdefault.jpg" style="display:none"/>    <!--Includes hidden thumbnail-->
        </description>

        <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<xsl:value-of select="$videoid" /></link>  <!--Link to video on YouTube-->
        <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<xsl:value-of select="$videoid" /></guid>


    </item>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ParseLink"> <!--YouTube automatically turns URLs into links, this performs the same function for RSS-->
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'http')">            
            <a href="http{substring-before(substring-after($text, 'http'), '&#xA;')}">Watch the complete video on our website</a>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="ParseText">    <!--Once the link is found, parses the rest of the text-->
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="ParseText"> <!--Replaces line breaks in the description to <br> tags-->
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>

        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#xA;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#xA;')"/>
            <br />
            <xsl:call-template name="ParseText">
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>

    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: What do your <xsl:stylesheet> attributes look like?  When you say "whole thing returns null", you mean the XSLT transformation does not do anything?  If you match without the namespace, you won't match anything...

Comment: My stylesheet is the same as the YouTube XML except instead of the regular xmlns tag, I have a xmlns:xsl tag (I added the exact contents of it to the original post).  As for the null thing, I'm using XSLPalette to do the transformations, and I think it just displays (null) whenever it doesn't compile correctly but there aren't any coding errors.

Comment: What do you mean by "before it will compile"? What are you compiling?

Comment: Also, what language are you using to apply the transformation?

Comment: Sorry, I use XSLPalette to apply transformations, so maybe "compiling" isn't the right word.  But basically, you select the XML document, the XSLT document, and click "Transform" and it applies the XSLT transformations to the XML document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your stylesheet does not work is because you don't have the Atom namespace defined...  The default namespace from YouTube is http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom.  If you want to match on the "feed" node, you would have a stylesheet like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" ... more stuff ... >
    <xsl:template match="/atom:feed">
        etc. etc.
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT:
Here's an example stylesheet that works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"         xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007" gd:etag="W/&quot;Ak8EQX47eCp7I2A9WhdSEkQ.&quot;">
    <xsl:template match="/atom:feed">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="atom:entry"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="atom:entry">
            <p>Entry:<xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
            </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT:
OK, Here's your updated stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"         xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"     xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/"     xmlns:gd="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005"     xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007"     gd:etag="W/&quot;Ak8EQX47eCp7I2A9WhdSEkQ.&quot;">
    <xsl:template match="/atom:feed">
        <xsl:for-each select="atom:entry">
            <item>
                <title>
                <xsl:value-of select="atom:title"/>
            </title>
            <xsl:variable name="videoid" select="substring-before(substring-after(media:group/media:content/@url, 'v/'), '?')"/>
            <!--Extracting the YouTube video ID-->
            <description>
                <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/{$videoid}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="never" allowfullscreen="true" width="500" height="300"/>
                <!--Embed code for the video-->
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <xsl:call-template name="ParseLink">
                    <!--Parses the video description such that URLs become links-->
                    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="media:group/media:description"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <img src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/{$videoid}/hqdefault.jpg" style="display:none"/>
                <!--Includes hidden thumbnail-->
            </description>
            <link>http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<xsl:value-of select="$videoid"/>
            </link>
            <!--Link to video on YouTube-->
            <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=<xsl:value-of select="$videoid"/>
            </guid>
        </item>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ParseLink">
    <!--YouTube automatically turns URLs into links, this performs the same function for RSS-->
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'http')">
            <a href="http{substring-before(substring-after($text, 'http'), '&#xA;')}">Watch the complete video on our website</a>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="ParseText">
                <!--Once the link is found, parses the rest of the text-->
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ParseText">
    <!--Replaces line breaks in the description to <br> tags-->
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text,'&#xA;')">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'&#xA;')"/>
            <br/>
            <xsl:call-template name="ParseText">
                <xsl:with-param name="text">
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'&#xA;')"/>
                </xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work.  For whatever reason, it only compiles when I leave the atom declaration out of both documents.

Comment: If you would post your XSLT, it would help a lot...  You can pare it down to the essentials, if possible.

Comment: Ok, added my source code.  My guess is everything after the </item> tag is irrelevant, but you can never be too careful...

Comment: I updated my answer to have a working XSLT for your feed.  Maybe you could refactor your XSLT to use a similar approach...

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for looking into this!  However, are there other steps needed to make this work for my code?  I replaced my stylesheet and template declarations with your code and it still didn't compile; would I need to add "atom:" before every tag?

Comment: Yes, you need the atom: prefix for all the atom elements...  I have edited my answer to include your stylesheet, working correctly.  You have an `<xsl:if>` that is testing something called "yt:position", but no such element exists in the feed, so that is why you get no results.  I removed the `<xsl:if>` and it is working.  I have spent a lot of time on this question, and I'd appreciate an upvote on my answer... :)

Comment: Hm, apparently I can't upvote?  So I just marked it "solved".  I haven't had a chance to test it out yet, but I'll give it a shot on Monday and I figure if this doesn't work, I might just leave it be.  Thanks so much for all your help!